# Why do I have to build my Domain Project that contains my EDMX before my application will run?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext, edmx

I have ASP.NET MVC application solution split into 3 projects:

- MyApp.Domain (EDMX File and Repositories)
- MyApp.Test (Unit Tests)
- MyApp.WebUI (MVC App)

When I get my application out of source control, set project `MyApp.WebUI` to the Startup project and F5 to run, I get an error from my DbContext...

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The Entity Framework provider type
>   'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6'
>   registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider
>   with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' could not be loaded. Make
>   sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is
>   available to the running application. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

However if I right mouse click and 'Build' on my `MyApp.Domain` project first and then run it, my application makes a connection just fine.

Shouldn't I be able to just click run and it should build them all and just work?

### Update 1

If I choose 'Rebuild all' or 'Build Solution' from the build menu, which I assume should rebuild all of my projects individually, it comes up with the error when I run it.

I have to actually choose 'Build' on my `MyApp.Domain` project within VS and then F5 my solution for my application to make a connection to the database without a DbContext error.

### Update 2

If I right mouse click my EDMX file and 'Run Custom Tool' (as suggested in this [Microsoft article to regenerate the EDMX code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/cc982041(v=vs.100).aspx)) and then F5 my solution to run, it still doesn't work.  I have also tried opening the EDMX and saving it.  It still comes up with the DbContext error.

### Update 3 - App Config File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="QuizEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/QuizModel.csdl|res://*/QuizModel.ssdl|res://*/QuizModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user id=root;database=uquiznew&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="owin:AppStartup" value="uQuiz.OwinStart" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.0.0" newVersion="5.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Maybe the `Domain` project appears to be out of date and, since it's a dependency, Visual Studio needs a "refresh".

Comment: I am getting my solution out of source control, I'm wondering if that might be affecting it..?  When you say it's out of date, what do you mean, shouldn't it build all of my projects when I press F5?

Comment: it might be that the `edmx` build adds a generation step that is missed otherwise.

Comment: Are you the only one working on the project? Can the project be modified by another developer? I'm no expert on this matter, I'm just guessing here, but I think that `Run` just does a incremental build, at best.

Comment: Yeah, I'm the only one working on it, I have it in my own personal SVN repository :).

Comment: Even if I do 'Rebuild all' OR 'Build Solution' from the Build menu it doesn't work, I have to choose that specific project `MyApp.Domain` and Build... then the application works.  It's really strange...

Comment: @DavinTryon Is there a way to force generation on build?

Comment: @DavinTryon Please see Update 2

Comment: post your app config file

Comment: @V2Solutions-MSTeam I have now posted the web.config file

Answer (score 1):

As Tim.Tang states in [their answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25071878/19679):

> In EF6, you need to use mysql connector 6.8.x, and add
>   DbConfigurationTypeAttribute to you DbContext:
>
> ```
> [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
> public class DemoContext : DbContext{}
> ```
>
> which MySqlEFConfiguration is in MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll in 6.8.x.

**AppConfig:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="QuizEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/QuizModel.csdl|res://*/QuizModel.ssdl|res://*/QuizModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user id=root;database=uquiznew&quot;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
     <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
     </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I can't believe that I missed this. Thank you for coming to my rescue!  You have inadvertently sorted this question of mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25967745/c-sharp-mysql-with-entity-framework-error-cant-update-edmx-file  I need to test to see if it will automatically build...

Comment: Sadly it didn't work for automatically building, I still have to rebuild my `MyApp.Domain` project to get it to work, but with the annotation I can update my database now!  Yippeee!

Comment: If you copy the words of another, you must provide proper attribution, as I have done in the above.